# Module Naming error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

So I wrote a module as such in rails:

```
module SpecUtil

  def login
    visit tasks_path
    click_link "Sign in"
    current_path == log_in_path
    fill_in "email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "password", :with => @user.password
    click_button "Save changes"
    current_path == tasks_path
    page.should have_content "You have logged in!"  
  end

  def create_comment
     visit tasks_path
     click_link @task.name
     current_path == task_path(@task)
     fill_in 'comment_comment', :with => 'I am a comment'
     click_button 'Create Comment'
  end

end
```

How ever when I include SpecUtil into my rails test file as such:

```
include SpecUtil
```

I get the error

```
/home/adam/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/StartPoint/spec/requests/categories_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SpecUtil (NameError)
```

This happens when I run guard. The file spec_util.rb exists in the same folder as the tests....

why is this spazzing out? - I read on stack that, the way I am including modules is correct...

Comment: Are you loading your rails env into your test environment? Traditionally it's added to a spec_helper.rb file.

Comment: require the file then include your module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually utility modules like this are put into `spec/support` directory. Make sure that your `spec/spec_helper.rb` has code which loads support files:

```
# Requires supporting files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in ./support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
```

and move your module to `spec/support/spec_util.rb`